# Drive on wheel dolly?

Tags: wheels, safety

My FWD got a clamp in the rear. Wise to dolly the wheel and drive off? Dolly both rear wheels or just the one? Is it safe on the motorway?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If you do this, please post a video on YouTube or elsewhere. I have popcorn and beer ready. You'll likely kill yourself - at least leave something behind that will discourage others from making your mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is absolutely ***NOT*** safe for you to do. A wheel dolly has four independent wheels on it, which allow the vehicle to go in *any* direction. By putting the wheel up on the dolly, you've taken away a great portion of stability which the car needs to track correctly. You risk your life, the life of your passengers, damaging your car, plus causing great amounts of havoc around you by doing so. Just pay the fine and get it removed.

Comment: I can jam the swivel.

Comment: I agree with Paul - this is a REALLY bad idea, and incredibly dangerous. In addition to Paul's comments - the bearings on the dolly would fail virtually instantly at any kind of speed, and you'll probably get arrested for dangerous driving...

Comment: @TobyWoolington - You're not serious, are you? My answer stands, as what you are describing is ***extremely*** dangerous. You wouldn't make it a 1/4 mile without causing issues for yourself or those around you. Realistically, you could go to jail for trying something like what you are suggesting. If not for evading a ticket, for causing mayhem and wanton destruction to other people's property.

Comment: Okay, cheers! Just asking. Angle grinder should do the trick.

Comment: Pay the fine and Park Proper...

Comment: It's also illegal, at least in the UK. Just...no